# Absolute positioning working without relative positioning in the parent

Tags: css, css-position

I am trying to wrap my head around a tutorial, where the `.dropdown-content` is placed `absolute`, but there is no parent containing the `relative` or `absolute` is there.

I have followed many tutorials, where it is mentioned that if there is no such parent, it will be attached to the `<body>` tag. Why is this absolute positioning is required here.

I also came across [this](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/#comment-916191), which talks about non necessity of such positioned parent.

Here's the code from the tutorial:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  # What is the significance of this,
  since there is no positioned parent. background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>
```

Comment: Tip: avoid using W3Schools as a learning resource.

Comment: If there is no positioned ancestor, an absolutely positioned element *does not* use the `body` as the containing block. It use the *initial containing block*, which would be the viewport.

Comment: @Michael_B: Doesn't getting attached to the viewport means that it will essentially be fixed in position? It is right, that in absence of parent positioned block,it uses the initial containing block. But, using viewport seems a bit confusing to me.

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-position-3/#def-cb

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#containing-block-details

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are no positions (`bottom`, `left`, `right` or `top`) defined for that element so it will therefore sit in the position it would sit in without the absolute positioning; all the absolute positioning is doing in this case is taking it out of the normal flow of the page so that it doesn't affect the size of its parent. Try removing the `position` property and see what happens.

You should also note that, if an absolutely positioned element is not a descendant of a positioned (be it `absolute`, `fixed`, `relative` or `sticky`) element then its positions are set relative to the viewport.

Comment: I see your point. Just to be double sure, the purpose of using absolute here is to prevent <ul> from taking up more space in height, right? As you have suggested to not use w3schools, is there any alternative way that this can be achieved? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your last paragraph is incorrect on multiple fronts. It doesn't have to be a descendant of a *relatively* positioned element. The ancestor just needs to be positioned (relative, absolute, fixed or sticky). And it doesn't position relative to `body` when there is no other positioned ancestor. It uses the initial containing block.

Comment: In this specific instance, yes that's all the absolute positioning is doing. However, you should always specify your positions to avoid any potential problems, now or in the future. W3Schools is not a well-trusted resource, there are plenty of other, much better resource out there, such as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/).

Comment: Sorry, @Michael_B, you are of course correct on your first point - I've had a horrific morning with servers crashing and hard drives failing on me so my brain isn't firing on all cylinders! Could you elaborate on what you mean by "initial containing block" in your second point?

Comment: D'oh! 2 rookie mistakes in one sentence - think I need to stay off SO for the rest of the day. Thanks for catching those and correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

Absolute - This is a very powerful type of positioning that allows you to literally place any page element exactly where you want it. You use the positioning attributes top, left bottom and right to set the location. Remember that these values will be relative to the next parent element with relative (or absolute) positioning. If there is no such parent, it will default all the way back up to the  element itself meaning it will be placed relatively to the page itself.
The trade-off, and most important thing to remember, about absolute positioning is that these elements are removed from the flow of elements on the page. An element with this type of positioning is not affected by other elements and it doesn't affect other elements. This is a serious thing to consider every time you use absolute positioning. It's overuse or improper use can limit the flexibility of your site.

In above example there of w3school there is no top bottom left right properties so it will not consider position with body.

Comment: why this downvote for it can anyone tell or just because of formatting?

Comment: I don't know who down voted your answer, but it might be the case that you have quoted this from some where without citing the source. Thanks for taking up time and answering this though. :)