# display: inline-block in CSS

Tags: html, css

I code a web site from a template at w3school. Here is my question:

why do these anchor elements(home, band, tour, contact) jump from the nav bar?
And Does anyone knows how to fix it?

I try to search from the internet but I dont't find any things. pls help me!

[here is my web site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZkuu.png)

[here is the template of my web site](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryw3css_templates_band.htm#)

thanks for helping...!

```css
/*reset CSS*/
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
html{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.header{
    height: 46.4px;
    background-color: black;
}
.header>.nav>.nav__item>a{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 46.4px;
    padding: 0px 24px;
}
.header>.nav>.nav__item{
    display: inline-block;/*to set in the same line*/
}

.header>.nav .sub_nav{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.header>.nav .sub_nav{
    /* display: none; */
}
.header>.nav .sub_nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.header>.nav li:hover>a{
    color: black !important;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.slider{
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="">Band</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="">Tour</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item">
                <a href="">More</a>
                <ul class="sub_nav">
                    <li><a href="">Merchandise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Extras</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Media</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="slider">

    </div>

    <div class="content">

    </div>

    <div class="footer">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add `.nav > li { outline: 1px dashed white }` to your style, and you will see why. To debug CSS, right click on an element, and then select _Inspect_ and you can hover over the elements to see how much space they take up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `position: absolute` to `sub_nav` so that it won't take up any space.

```css
/*reset CSS*/
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
html{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.header{
    height: 46.4px;
    background-color: black;
}
.header>.nav>.nav__item>a{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 46.4px;
    padding: 0px 24px;
}
.header>.nav>.nav__item{
    display: inline-block;/*to set in the same line*/
}

.header>.nav .sub_nav{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.header>.nav .sub_nav{
    position: absolute;
}
.header>.nav .sub_nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
.header>.nav li:hover>a{
    color: black !important;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.slider{
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="">Band</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="">Tour</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item">
                <a href="">More</a>
                <ul class="sub_nav">
                    <li><a href="">Merchandise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Extras</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Media</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="slider">

    </div>

    <div class="content">

    </div>

    <div class="footer">

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tks, it works. i understand position: absolute but i don't know why it can fix my code. can u explain?

Comment: @KhánhPhạm We know that for `position: absolute`, it will find the first positioned relative parent. However, in this case such element does not exist. Therefore, the element will just [sit in the original position without the absolute positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38144953/absolute-positioning-working-without-relative-positioning-in-the-parent#38145077). All the absolute positioning is doing in this case is just taking the `<ul>` out of the document flow. Therefore, it won't make the `nav` larger in height.

Comment: @KhánhPhạm also if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thanks!

Comment: tks. i just research about out of flow and i understand your explain about why it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can just add `display:flex` to `ul.nav{}`

```
ul.nav {
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Tks. it also can fix my code. But can u explain why ul element sub_nav affect to my code. Because without that ul element, my code can run properly

Answer (score 0):

**I think you are looking for this.**

*Try this it will work for you.*

```css
    body,
div {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0 none;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: rgb(65, 63, 63);

}



.md {
    background-color: black;
    /* padding: 15px; */


}

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;
}

a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(224, 224, 224);
    color: black;
}

.dropbtn {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: white;
    padding: 19px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;

}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;

}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>


<body>



    <div class="md">

        <a href="">HOME</a>
        <a href="">BAND</a>
        <a href="">TOUR</a>
     

<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">MORE ▼</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

    </div>








</body>

</html>
```

**Let me know if I help you.**

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: ok..I'll remember this from next time Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is apply `display: none` to `.header>.nav .sub_nav` and on hover apply `display : block` to `.sub_nav` with `.header>.nav .nav__item:hover .sub_nav`.

**Working Fiddle**

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
    height: 46.4px;
    background-color: black;
}

.header>.nav>.nav__item>a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 46.4px;
    padding: 0px 24px;
}

.header>.nav>.nav__item {
    display: inline-block;
    /*to set in the same line*/
}

.header>.nav .sub_nav {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.header>.nav .sub_nav {
    display: none;

    cursor: auto;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 160px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
.header>.nav .nav__item:hover .sub_nav {
    display: block;
}

.header>.nav .sub_nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    /* color: white; */
    color: black;
}

.header>.nav li:hover>a {
    color: black !important;
    background-color: #ccc;
}

.slider {
    background-color: #333;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="header">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="">Band</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="">Tour</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item"><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="nav__item">
                <a href="">More</a>
                <ul class="sub_nav">
                    <li><a href="">Merchandise</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Extras</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Media</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="slider">
    </div>

    <div class="content">
    </div>
    
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```